# How to Get the wall layer material color using Revit api

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to retrieve the colors of wall layers but when I use Material.Color method I only get RGB value(117,117,117) but the RGB value in revit is 0,255,0 How I get this exact value in code

Material materialColor = material.Color;

Can it possible to get the color of material layers for wall element.

Comment: How to get Material color for family instance through API

Answer (score 0):

try the builtInParameter.MATERIAL_PARAM_COLOR

then you get RGB  value with the properties 
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/c0ce7b93-3ff1-4194-914e-e4ca7cb771d1.htm

Comment: Hi Thanks , I tried with this method but the parameter value I am getting is null,                     colourParam = familyInstance.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.MATERIAL_PARAM_COLOR);                  In my case the colourParam is null.

Answer (score 0):

Revit provides an entire hierarchy of control mechanisms to determine the material and colour of an element. Therefore, you may need to determine what property is contriolling that specific wall's specific layer's specific colour. The Building Coder provides a [topic group on controlling element colour and material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.24) that ought to tell you all you need to know.